# FontAwesome not displaying letter "o"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, sass, webfonts

I'm trying to include [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) into my project but I cannot get the letter little "o" to work,

My font-awesome.css.scss.erb

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  src: url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.eot') %>');
  src: url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.eot') + '?#iefix' %>') format('eot'),              url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.woff') %>') format('woff'), url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.ttf') %>') format('truetype'), url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.svg') + '#FontAwesome' %>') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

// Other stuff,,,,,,
```

my own css

```
 body {
   font-family: "FontAwesome"
 }
```

What happens is that the text changes to some serif font, soo something is changing, but the letter "o" is not displayed, I tried various gems but none seems to work.

I also tried different browsers (Chrome, FF, Safari)

As OS I Use Lion 10.7.5

I have also configured the assets path.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using FontAwesome as the font face for your body. You'll want to restrict it to a particular class or something like that.

Comment: I tried that, I don't know why it would make a difference though?

Comment: I looked into it and you are correct, I missunderstand the use of FontAwesome

Answer (score 2):

[FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) requires you to use the [`font-awesome.css`](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/css/font-awesome.css) stylesheet.

Then you will create an element to use the font-face such as:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<i class="fa fa-download"> Download</i>
```

See [*Not using Boostrap?*](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/get-started/#not-using-bootstrap)<sup>1</sup> at http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome for directions

<sub>1. This exists in the Old 3.2.1 documentation.</sub>

Comment: I'm using the font-awesome.scss instead which is basicly the same thing, I am able to use the element you posted.

Comment: I attached a Screenshot how it looks